# Legend in plot not showing, also y-axis not showing all labels

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I am really new to programming.
I want to plot some data and everything is working besides my legend with some data about the linear regression I did.
Also the y axis seems to not be properly formatted, because the first and last label are not showing like on the x axis.
Could somebody explain me, how I get my text-legend to show and how I format the axis properly?

```
x <- c(0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 700, 600, 500, 400, 300, 200, 100, 0)
y <- c(7.93, 8.38, 8.79, 9.08, 9.4, 9.72, 10.04, 10.35, 10.66, 10.37, 10.06, 9.73, 9.41, 9.06, 8.64, 8.36, 7.93)
x_name <- "gewicht"
y_name <- "auslenkung"
df <- data.frame(x,y)
names(df) <- c(x_name, y_name)
plot(df$gewicht, df$auslenkung,
     xaxt = "n",
     yaxt = "n",
     col = "red",
     xlab = "Belastung [g]",
     ylab = "Längenänderung [mm]",
     main = "Änderung des Länge eines Messingdrahtes",
     frame.plot = FALSE)
axis(1, at = seq(0, 800, by = 100), las= 2)
axis(2, at = seq(7.5, 11, by = 0.5), las= 2)

fit1 <- lm(auslenkung ~ gewicht, data = df)
abline(fit1, lty = "dashed")
text(x = , y = 0,labels= "slope = 3.391e-03 \n intercept = 8.012e+00 \n R2 = 0.9967 \n P = 2.2e-16")
```

I am really really inexperienced, so every help is welcome.

Plot with properly formatted x-axis and wrong y-axis, also no text box showing:

[image]

Comment: In your final `text` statement,  you have `x =`    with no value specified.  Also,  you specified y=0 which would be way off the screen.   try `x=600, y=8.2`

Comment: Oh, you are right. I had, at one point, but I changed the values, and then I forgot them, before I posted the code. 
Thanks, know I can see it :)

Comment: @B.Tarno If my answer below gave a solution to your question, please mark is as accepted. This prevents other users to spend their time on already answered questions. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` and `y` arguments in the `text()` function are related to the corresponding coordinates of the data. Thus you can specify the values according to where your text legend should appear. There's no space required after a `\n`.

```
text(x = 50, y = 9, labels= "slope = 3.391e-03 \nintercept = 8.012e+00 \nR2 = 0.9967 \nP = 2.2e-16")
```

To correct y-axis issue just add `ylim = c(7.5, 11)` inside `plot(.)`.

After you have done this, it's probably best to export the plot e.g. via `png()`.

```
png("test.png", width=1080, height=720, res = 100)
plot(df$gewicht, df$auslenkung, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", col = "red", 
     xlab = "Belastung [g]", ylab = "Längenänderung [mm]", 
     main = "Änderung des Länge eines Messingdrahtes", ylim = c(7.5, 11),
     frame.plot = FALSE)
axis(1, at = seq(0, 800, by = 100), las= 2)
axis(2, at = seq(7.5, 11, by = 0.5), las= 2)
fit1 <- lm(auslenkung ~ gewicht, data = df)
abline(fit1, lty = "dashed")
text(x = 50, y = 9, labels= "slope = 3.391e-03 \nintercept = 8.012e+00 \nR2 = 0.9967 \nP = 2.2e-16")
dev.off()
```

***Yielding***

[image]

You could play around a little with the coordinates to put your legend at the desired place.

The plot will be saved into your working directory (use `getwd()` to locate it).